# Using find_all in bs4

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, request

I am encountering an issue in my Python script while attempting to parse multiple classes using BeautifulSoup. The error message specifically points to line 12, stating, "ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element."

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

heroes_page_list=[]


url = f'https://dota2.fandom.com/wiki/Dota_2_Wiki'
q = requests.get(url)
result = q.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(result, 'lxml')

heroes = soup.find_all('div', class_= 'heroentry').find('a')
for hero in heroes:
    hero_url = heroes.get('href')
    heroes_page_list.append("https://dota2.fandom.com" + hero_url)
# print(heroes_page_list)

with open ('heroes_page_list.txt', "w") as file:
    for line in heroes_page_list:
        file.write(f'{line}\n')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching `a` tag inside a list of `div` tags you need to do like this,

```
heroes = soup.find_all('div', class_= 'heroentry')
a_tags = [hero.find('a') for hero in heroes]
for a_tag in a_tags:
    hero_url = a_tag.get('href')
    heroes_page_list.append("https://dota2.fandom.com" + hero_url)
```

`heroes_page_list` look like this,

```
['https://dota2.fandom.com/wiki/Abaddon',
 'https://dota2.fandom.com/wiki/Alchemist',
 'https://dota2.fandom.com/wiki/Axe',
 'https://dota2.fandom.com/wiki/Beastmaster',
 'https://dota2.fandom.com/wiki/Brewmaster',
 'https://dota2.fandom.com/wiki/Bristleback',
 'https://dota2.fandom.com/wiki/Centaur_Warrunner',
 ....
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is stating everything you need to do.

[find()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) method is only usable on a single element. [find_all()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) returns a list of elements. You are trying to apply `find()` to a `list` of elements.

If you want to apply `find('a')` you should to something similar to this:

```
heroes = soup.find_all('div', class_= 'heroentry')
for hero in heroes:
    hero_a_tag = hero.find('a')
    hero_url = hero_a_tag .get('href')
    heroes_page_list.append("https://dota2.fandom.com" + hero_url)
```

You basically have to apply the `find()` method on every element presents in the list generated by the `find_all()` method